# Faraday - Can I use outbound proxy for requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud-foundry, faraday, faraday-oauth

My app works great on localhost. Our Cloud Foundry setup somehow does not have outbound connectivity... so I have been told I can get outbound connectivity through a proxy.

What do I need to change in my Faraday requests to use that proxy?

My code and how I am supposed to connect.

```
url = "#{@config[:host]}#{@config[:login_path]}"
c = Faraday.new(:url => url,
                :request => { :timeout => 20, :open_timeout => 5},
                :ssl => {:verify => false}) do |f|
  f.request :url_encoded
  f.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
  f.response :json, :content_type => /\bjson$/
end

  @resp = c.post(url, {username: username, password: password,
    deviceId: @config[:device_id], deviceName: @config[:device_name], deviceType: @config[:device_type],
    appId: @config[:app_id], scope: @config[:scope]})
```

This is how I am supposed to use the proxy that was set up.

"Once your service is bound, the application will have service definition in JSON format in `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable you can see the format using `cf env x-explorer` command. Your app will need to parse and setup proxy using the given credentials.

Here is an example of the credentials. You can use only `uri` or individual parameters: `host`, `port`, `username` and `password`"

```
uri: http://2abcf906-127e-495c-ae71-c69712862292:616e714aea0cfc81de67ad1445cf1448e38d6a8db345a452c0e1ddc830b8f132@f.services.g1.app.cloud.my_company.net:49349
host: f.services.g1.app.cloud.my_company.net
port: 49349
username: 2abcf906-127e-495c-ae71-c69712862292
password: 616e714aea0cfc81de67ad1445cf1448e38d6a8db345a452c0e1ddc830b8f132
```

Again, app works great on localhost. No outbound connectivity with company Cloud Foundry setup. I have bound the service, so that is fine.

What do I add to have my outbound requests go through the proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
url = "#{@config[:host]}#{@config[:login_path]}"
c = Faraday.new(:url => url,
                :request => { :timeout => 20, :open_timeout => 5},
                :ssl => {:verify => false}) do |f|
  f.request :url_encoded
  f.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
  f.response :json, :content_type => /\bjson$/url = "#{@config[:host]}#{@config[:login_path]}"
c = Faraday.new(:url => url,
                :request => { :timeout => 20, :open_timeout => 5},
                :ssl => {:verify => false}) do |f|
  f.request :url_encoded
  f.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
  f.response :json, :content_type => /\bjson$/
  f.proxy = "http://2abcf906-127e-495c-ae71-c69712862292:616e714aea0cfc81de67ad1445cf1448e38d6a8db345a452c0e1ddc830b8f132@f.services.g1.app.cloud.my_company.net:49349"
end

  @resp = c.post(url, {username: username, password: password,
    deviceId: @config[:device_id], deviceName: @config[:device_name], deviceType: @config[:device_type],
    appId: @config[:app_id], scope: @config[:scope]})

end

  @resp = c.post(url, {username: username, password: password,
    deviceId: @config[:device_id], deviceName: @config[:device_name], deviceType: @config[:device_type],
    appId: @config[:app_id], scope: @config[:scope]})
```

Here they says how to set up a proxy on faraday request doing

```
conn = Faraday.new(url, ssl: {verify:false}) do |conn|
  # middleware ...
  conn.adapter <adapter>

  conn.proxy "http://localhost:80"
end
```

https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/issues/221

Comment: Thank you. I will try it on Monday morning sir!

Comment: What about the username and password I am supposed to use for the proxy? It looks like I have to log into the proxy with Faraday... See the second code block in my question.

Comment: look at http://www.rubydoc.info/github/lostisland/faraday/Faraday/Connection   :proxy   - URI, String or Hash of HTTP proxy options
          (default: "http_proxy" environment variable).
          :uri      - URI or String
          :user     - String (optional)
          :password - String (optional)